# Transaction log is full and does not free up space

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a database in SQL Server 2005 whose transaction log becomes full. It is using snapshot replication. I noticed the transaction log is not freeing up space. So I created an additional transaction log. Three days has passed and this first transaction log is still full. I performed a full database backup and transaction backup. Then I tried to shrink the transaction log but the shrink failed.

Can anyone advise why shrinking transaction log is failing? ANy other recommendation on how to resolve the problem?

Comment: Could you add some information about the error received with the transaction log fails?  It's impossible to troubleshoot an error without the error details...

Comment: Is this a first occurrence after a period of normal operation?  If so, have there been any recent configuration changes?  Is this a brand new set up?  All bit of a follow-on to what Scott posted.

Answer (score 1):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/110139

http://www.sql-server-citation.com/2009/08/how-to-get-rid-off-from-transaction-log.html - good explanation including help (commands to analyze etc.)

;) have fun. Seriously - you need to do some analysis now.